# Find a binary operation * on $\Bbb Q$ such that $f:(\Bbb Q,+)\rightarrow (\Bbb Q,*)$ is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a binary operation * on $\Bbb Q$ such that  $f:(\Bbb Q,+)\rightarrow (\Bbb Q,*)$ is an isomorphism

$f(x)=3x-1$

Approach
I already proved that $f$ is bijective now I have to find *, so $f$ is homomorphic .

$f(a+b)=f(a)*f(b)$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb Q$

so $$3(a+b)-1=(3(a)-1)*(3(b)-1)$$

what would be a good one?

Comment: does $(Q, *)$ need to be a group?, or can $*$ be any binary operation?

Comment: What is $Q$? Is it $\Bbb Q$ or something else?

Comment: * can be any binary operation

Comment: *paf, Yes, rationals

Comment: Hint: given two groups $G$, $H$ and a bijection $f:G\to H$, $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if for every $g,h\in H$, $gh=f(f^{-1}(g)f^{-1}(h))$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $f$ is a bijection with inverse $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x+1}{3}$. Since you want $f$ to be an isomorphism, so is $f^{-1}$.

Therefore 
$$f^{-1}(x*y)=f^{-1}(x)+f^{-1}(y) \\
f^{-1}(x*y)=\frac{x+y+2}{3}
$$

Now apply $f$ to this relation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $*$ can be any binary operation, $a*b= a+b+1$ should do the trick.

Comment: Ohhh ok, I was actually constrained by standard operations such  as +,-,/,*, but now I understand you can define operations with such structures.

Comment: Just to point out to the person who asked the question how * can be obtained as such...it's not too difficult to see that if * were simply addition, then the LHS and RHS of the equation you posted is nearly equal. However, on the RHS you end up with a -2 instead of a -1, so you can throw in a "+1" to how you want to define * in order to offset that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to find such an $\ast$ (and in fact show that there's only a single choice of $\ast$). You've already shown that $f$ is a bijection, and since the operation $+$ is already given, we can 'push forward' $+$ through $f$ to get the desired $\ast$.

To understand this a bit more, you've come up with the equation 
$$3(a+b)-1=(3a-1)\ast (3b-1)$$
or (turning it around)
$$(3a-1)\ast (3b-1)=3(a+b)-1$$
We want to give a formula for $x\ast y$ for any $x,y$, and since you've shown that $f$ is a bijection, we know there are $a,b$ so that $f(a)=x=3a-1$ and $f(b)=y=3b-1$ (namely, $a=(x+1)/3$ and $b=(y+1)/3$).  Hence, we can rewrite this as
$$x\ast y=3(a+b)-1 = 3((x+1)/3+(y+1)/3)-1=x+y+1$$

Answer (score 1):

For $a,b \in \mathbb Q$ let $a * b := a+b +1$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
f(a) * f(b) &= (3a-1) * (3b-1) \\
&= (3a-1)+(3b-1) +1 \\
&= 3(a+b) -1 \\
&= f(a+b).
\end{align*}
$$

How does one obtain such a solution without black magic?

Well, let $a = f(\bar{a})$, $b = f(\bar{b})$, i.e. $\bar{a} = \frac{a+1}{3}$ and $\bar{b} = \frac{b+1}{3}$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
a * b &= f(\bar{a}) * f(\bar{b}) \\
&= f(\bar{a} + \bar{b}) \\
&= 3(\bar{a} + \bar{b}) - 1 \\
&= 3( \frac{a+1}{3} + \frac{b+1}{3}) - 1 \\
&= a + b + 1.
\end{align*}
$$

The key point is the second line in the second equation. We set $f(\bar{a}) * f(\bar{b}) = f(\bar{a} + \bar{b})$, because this is the equation we want to fullfill. So by 'pretending' that this equation holds, we obtain the unique definition of $*$ that actually satisfies this identity.

Comment: This also proves the uniqueness of $*$ and this is a good approach to keep in mind: We took any $*$ that satisfied the required condition and thereby obtained the unqiue solution that actually does satisfy it. It won't always work out this nicely, but often that's a good angle of attack.